# I need a batch file that will return the user name for inclusion in a popup. this in Win 7

Tags: file, batch-file

I maintain several remote computers, all Win 7, and need a batch file that will return the current user name from the task manager and put the result in a popup on the remote computer. I know that I can ask the user but it would be uncomfortable if they are watching inappropriate content. The "they" are my grand-kids.
Bill

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1 delims= " %%u in ('quser /SERVER:REMOTE_COMP_NAME') do (
  set "remote_user=%%u"
)

msg  %remote_user% /servername:REMOTE_COMP_NAME /w "hello you grand-descendant!!"
```

?